# how to receive emails from a ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am in dead end! i am trying to make an app to receive emails on hotmail! i created a method and i am getting an error and no email receiving..

in my method:

```
class Recivemail < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :from, :subject

 def sendmail(content,from,subject)
    subject = 'subject'
    recipients = "linkinpark_8884@hotmail.com"
    from = 'from'
    sent_on = Time.now
  end 
end
```

in config>enviroments>development.rb

```
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings ={
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address => 'smtp.hotmail.com',
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :domain => 'localhost:3000',
    :user_name => 'linkinpark_8884@hotmail.com',
    :password => 'mypass'

  }
```

in views>recivemails>show

`<%=@recivemail.sendmail(@recivemail.from,@recivemail.subject,@recivemail.content)%>`

everything seems to working correct except that i am not getting any email
any ideas??

Answer (score 3):

> `@recivemail.send(@recivemail.from,@recivemail.subject,@recivemail.content)`

The `send` method in Ruby means "send a message to this object" (as-in call the method that is named by the first parameter to `send`). What you're doing here is trying call a method named by the value of `@recivemail.from` to the object `@recivemail`.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send

In your code, the method is named `sendmail` not `send` anyway.

(I would not put this into a view either, but that seems to be the least of your troubles right now.)

As for your original question about receiving emails in general, start [with this article](http://railspikes.com/2007/6/1/rails-email-processing). It was written several years ago, but should give you some ideas.

Comment: lol so noobish!!! i am trying to learn ror!! thx that is correct :))
But still no email receiving..

Comment: It's confusing that you have a method called `sendmail` in a class called `ReceiveMail`. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish, and since it looked like you were just exploring Rails anyway, I wanted to help with the problems that jumped out at me.

Comment: i am trying to make an app that a user can send me email.. i must download the actionmailer packed? i have no idea why is not working now that i fixed this...

Comment: try putting deliver! on the Mail object and make sure u set the recipient correct you might also need to put sendmail in ur terminal to execute local delivery. also check ur log on deliver

Comment: i have put Recivemail.deliver_sendmail in method but says undefined method `deliver_sendmail' for #<Class:0x40605f0>... what i have done wrong? @dennis

Comment: The syntax is off you need to define your email and bind the action of delivery such as in:  def after_save(model)
    OrderMailer.confirmation_mail(model).deliver
  end